# Ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Пишу парсер, использую при этом библиотеку Beautiful soup. У при выполнение функции выскакивает ошибка, которая указана в заголовке

Пример функции:

```
def parse_link(html):
links=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table', id='products')
body=table.find('tbody')
for link_tr in sort_links(body):
    link_td=link_tr.find('td',class_='div_naimen')
    link_a=link_td.find('a')
    if link_a[0].has_attr('title'):
        links.append(link_a[1].get('href'))
    else:
        links.append(link_a[0].get('href'))
return links

def sort_links(body):
sort_links=[]
link_trs = body.find_all('tr')
for tableTr in link_trs:
    if  'subtitle' in tableTr.get('class'):
        link_trs.remove(tableTr)
for link_tr in link_trs:        
    if 'tr_analog' not in link_tr.get('class'):
        if 'tr_ucenka' not in link_tr.get('class'):
            sort_links.append(link_tr)
return sort_links
```

В ошибке указана строка:

```
    link_a = link_td.find('a')
```

Хотя, если просто выводить link_td, то получается:

```
[<td class="div_naimen" rowspan="1">
     <a href="#">string</a>
     <img alt="Посмотреть видео про товар" border="0" class="grey" height="12" onclick="zoom_picture_new(1010143,1)" src="/misc/ico_video.gif" title="Посмотреть видео про товар" width="16"/></td>
```

И в нем, есть тег (a), а также вывелся именно тег (td), и к нему я могу применить функцию find()

Буду рад любому ответу

(Пишу впревые на форум, поэтому извините,если что-то упустил для решение моего вопроса)

Comment: NoneType означает что у тебя какая-то переменная не объявлена внимательно осмотри код как живой отладчик и сделай вывод

Comment: Метод `link_tr.find('td',class_='div_naimen')` не нашёл нужного вам тега и вернул `None`, далее Вы пытаетесь у этого `None` вызвать метод `find()`. Дебажьте, смотрите, что возвращает `link_tr.find('td',class_='div_naimen')` на каждой итерации.

Comment: Спасибо, весьма благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, на какой-то из итераций `for link_tr in sort_links(body):` код `link_td=link_tr.find('td',class_='div_naimen')` ничего не нашел и вернул `None`. А дальше вы пытаетесь у `None`, у которого нет ничего, вызвать метод `find`

Пройдитесь по всем итерациям дебаггером, он поможет понять, на какой из итераций проблема.

Comment: Все верно, когда я все проверил, действительно оказалось, что в том списке с атрибутами (td) присутсвовал None и, когда я проверил сам тег (link_tr),который соотвествует тегу None, оказалось, что в этом теге отсутствует тег (td) и поэтому мне выдовала ошибку. Спасибо!